# Spring Data JPA - cannot insert to the databse - annotation problem?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I can't resolve the problem with inserting values into my database.

I've two very basic and simple classes - Car and Model. I want to store the model ID value for each vehicle in the car class. You know, for the sake of simplicity I assume every car has no brand, only model (eg. Auris, Civic, F150, Challenger etc.).

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Model model;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Model {
    @Id
    private final Long id;
    private final String name;
    private final int price;
}
```

But the problem is I got that error

> Field error in object 'car' on field 'model': rejected value [Model(id=2, name=Civic)]; codes [typeMismatch.samochod.model,typeMismatch.model,typeMismatch.com.CarDealer.Model,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [car.model,model]; arguments []; default message [model]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.CarDealer.Model' for property 'model'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Model(id=2, name=Civic)'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Model(id=2,name=Civic)"]]

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Your `Model` class has `@RequiredArgsConstructor` lombok annotation, which has created a public constructor of all final class variables. So it looks like that you are providing only two values in constructor. Please check that.

Comment: It seems like your app is providing a `String` for the `model` property instead of an `id` (presumably). When do you get this error? Could post the corresponding code, please?

Comment: Actually the problem was in frontend part of the application, since it's really not my cup of tea. Now, I'm testing it using postman, and it's working fine, but is there a way to send POST reqeust with a result of GET request? Eg. { "model" : "localhost:8080/getmodel/1" }.